# Maintaining multiple patches/feature branches for multiple development branches (and tags) in parallel

Tags: git, fork, patch, branching-and-merging

We have forked a project in git(hub) and want to maintain a few patches in our fork while also recreating those patches in their releases (tags) and release branches.

### Initial repository structure

The upstream structure is pretty simple:

```
origin/trunk A---B---D---F---H---...
                  \
origin/0.9         C---E---G---...
                       |
                   (tag 0.9)
```

### The problem

The upstream project increased the version of a dependency in commits `A` and `D` but those were mainly for convenience and we're sure that we can maintain a compatibility release for a while.

I've created a feature branch `trunk_compat` and used `git revert --no-commit` to create patches for commits `A` and `D` as we need them. I've branched this off `origin/trunk`

```
mine/trunk_compat              A*---D*
                              / 
origin/trunk A---B---D---F---H-...
                  \
origin/0.9         C---E---G---...
                       |
                   (tag 0.9)
```

So now it is quite easy for me to follow `origin/trunk` and maintain my patches by rebasing or merging depending on if I publish this or not.

Our *goal* is to maintain these patches for both branches (`trunk` and `0.9`) as well as recreate a release version of `0.9` (as it is tagged from `E`).

And I'm at a loss how do to this properly.

- I need a `0.9_compat` branch which has all commits up to `G` but also includes our patches `A*` and `D*` so we can put that into our continuous integration server and see if it works
- I need a tag `0.9_compat` that has the state of `E` with `A*` and `D*` applied.

  - To make it more complicated commit `E` is actually a backport of `D` onto the `0.9` branch so our `D*` patch should also be applied here
  - This isn't a proper merge or rebase because the upstream project is in SVN and this is git-svn mirror we're forking
- In the future upstream will branch `0.10` etc. and we want to maintain our patches on those branches as well

I can do this with cherry picking a lot or just applying patches manually (I think) but that does not feel right and I think I don't utilize git to its full extent.

Comment: don't know anything better than cherry picking here.

Comment: Thanks. I've gone that way now too. It looks rather clunky but it seems to work.

For the already existing branch I cherry-picked my patches and then rebased them so they are in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that you can do this, and you got them correctly - rebase (includes cherry-pick and patch, same result in the end) or merge.

1. Set up all the branches you need patched and apply the patches (`origin/trunk` and `origin/0.9_compat`).
2. Apply the patches on the branches
3. The difference is only in the *maintaining* strategy, which is `git pull` (merge) vs `git pull --rebase` (rebase) for these branches.

The difference between the strategies is that for `git pull`, git will try to merge the remote changes into your local branch (resulting in you having lots of git merge commits, but your patch sha will stay the same) and for `git pull --rebase` git will first fetch the remote changes and only then try to apply your local changes on top (resulting in your patch sha changing after every pull). I would argue that rebase is more appropriate (this argument is stronger if remote repo is originally git), because you will always be staying at the HEAD of the project + your patches, without an unnecessary merge commit mess.